# How do I save a web API to JSON file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been pulling my hair out for a couple of hours now trying to find out how to make a JavaScript code that would save web API data into a JSON file. I'm using this API https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=578080

Any ideas?

Comment: You really need to narrow down your problem. How are you running the JS (Windows Scripting Host? Node.js? A Firefox Extension? A `<script>` element in a web page? Something else?)

Comment: Are you having problems fetching the data? Parsing the data? Converting the parsed data to JSON? Saving the data in a file?

Comment: I'm running it with Node.js ... I'm trying to make my steam trading bot, and it's all done except for this part. I need to get fresh data about prices from opskins...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', webApiResponse, function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Answer (score -1):

For a Node app, use this:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
var file = '/tmp/data.json'
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
  console.dir(obj)
})
```

See here for more:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to save it to a local file automatically within the code, because my bot works with it. And it would have to overwrite that file every 30min with freshly gathered data.